# OnClick event upon clicking FileUpload button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to fire an `OnClick` event upon clicking the *asp:FileUpload* button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flash code it will file uploader as button which is clickable. but for this you need to download swfupload.swf file.

```
    <input type="file" id="uplaodExcel" name="uplaodExcel" />
```

following is the javascript code:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
    HideError();
    $("#uplaodExcel").makeAsyncUploader({
        upload_url: 'EventName',//Event you want to occur on click
        flash_url: '../Scripts/swfupload.swf',//flash file path that you download
        button_image_url: '@Url.Content("~/Content/blankButton.png")',// for button style
        file_size_limit: "10MB",
        file_types: "*.XLS; *.xlsx", //File extension you can provide any
        disableDuringUpload: 'INPUT[type="submit"]',
        upload_success_handler: function (file, server_data, receivedResponse) {
            var data = "";
            try {
                // you can add your code here
            } catch (e) { }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) an input of type file can support all standard [events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).
so what you can do is wirte to your control a javascript event for the click:

```
YOURCONTROL.Attributes.Add("onclick","YourLogic");
```